# Latex font not read in Illustrator

Tags: fonts, illustrator

I am having this problem for some time now. I am using the `Roboto-Regular` and `Roboto-Light` fonts in my tex documents (Miktex 2.9 on Win7) as per instructions from [this site](http://math.stanford.edu/~jyzhao/latexfonts.php).

An example of the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\roboR[1]{{\usefont{T1}{Roboto-Regular}{m}{n} #1 }}
\newcommand\roboL[1]{{\usefont{T1}{Roboto-Light}{m}{n} #1 }}

\begin{document}
\section*{Roboto Regular}
\roboR{\lipsum[1]}
\section*{Roboto Light}
\roboL{\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

With Latex->PDF it outputs a good result. When i load the output PDF in Illustrator, the Roboto fonts do not get recognized - this:

[image: Illustrator PDF]

I have set `pdftexDownloadBase14=true` in `updmap.cfg` and it does nothing.

When I load the PDF in Inkscape the `Roboto-Regular` font is used instead of the `Roboto-Light`. I can then set the `Roboto-Light` manually where I need it and just save the PDF from Inkspace (although Inkscape sometimes mixes up the formatting). Illustrator recognizes then the fonts in the PDF and all is good.

The thing is that there is a lot of the files to be processed, and I have a script that does Latex -> Illustrator -> ...

How to make Latex embed fonts or Illustrator recognize them? This seems to be an age-old thing. I have tried with [this](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/roboto) to no avail.

Thank you.

---

### EDIT:

I did try the process with `Illustrator CS6` with no success.

In the end, I have given up on the solution relaying entirely on `Illustrator`. Since I needed to produce scalar and vector image formats of the tex files, I use now `Photoshop` to load the PDF and produce scalar images and `Acrobat Reader Pro XI` to produce vector images (eps) as it reads the fonts correctly.

This 'fault' may be on the `Illustrator` side since I got a feeling that others have similar problems with Illustrator: [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1288158) and [this](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1330167) (from adobe forum) for example - I do not have the energy required to pursue this further.

By the way - [this](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latexs-friends/61-latexs-friends-others/381-combining-latex-and-illustrator) (installing fonts as system-wide fonts) works as it should on `amsmath` fonts.

Regards to all.

---

Comment: *Are* the fonts embedded? By default, they should be (at least in TeX Live and I assume in MiKTeX) but if you have changed the default configuration, that might not be the case. These fonts are certainly not part of the base 14 group, though. Check whether the fonts are embedded in your favourite PDF viewer. That will tell you whether the problem is that they aren't embedded or something else.

Comment: @cfr Adobe Acrobat Reader displays the font appropriately, but Illustrator does not, even as it has the fonts in his font selection - I can use these fonts in Illustrator - yet he refuses to load them with the PDFs.

EDIT: I will try a different version of Illustrator - who knows.

Comment: Any additional news here?

Comment: @Paul I got the ping in the mail for this. I stopped working on this some time ago when the work was done. I am looking right now at the scripts I used, but for can't really remember what procedure I used.

However, I could not solve it in a single script, I had several smaller scripts any maybe some manual editing.  

Good luck if you have the same/similar problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by the OP by some unknown method and it won't provide value to future visitors as-is.